# Find the pixel of bitmap irrespective Imageview size and scaletype

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I want to map the pixel of bitmap to Imageview x,y coordinate irrespective of Imageview size and Scaletype. e.g If same image is displayed in 3 Imageviews with different size and scaletype when user touch in first imageview on nose of image then I want to add button on nose on remaining two images.

Till now I have managed to detect on what pixel user has touched like this

```
imageView1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        float[] eventXY = new float[] { eventX, eventY };

        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
        ((ImageView) view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

        invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
        int pixelX = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
        int pixelY = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now... This is how I have converted pixelX,pixelY to imageview coordinates this is working fine  if Imageviews are in the same ratio as of original image....

```
private void addButtonInLayout2(RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout, float pixelX, float pixelY, ImageView mImageView) {
mImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    final int imageviewWidth = mImageView.getWidth();
    final int imageviewHeight = mImageView.getHeight();
    Drawable imgDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();
    int buttonX = (int) ((pixelX * imageviewWidth) / (mBitmap.getWidth()));
    int buttonY = (int) ((pixelY * imageviewHeight) / (mBitmap.getHeight()));
    System.out.println("buttonX  ===========   " + buttonX);
    System.out.println("buttonY  ===========   " + buttonY);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
    mParams.setMargins(buttonX, buttonY, 0, 0);
    mRelativeLayout.removeView(yellowButton);
    mRelativeLayout.addView(yellowButton, mParams);
    mRelativeLayout.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: `irrespective of Imageview size and Scaletype` - then you cant guarantee that the same x,y is in the same position of any other scaled image!

Comment: use getImageMatrix for those two ImageViews and call mapPoints to get mapped point for top and left coordinate of a Button to be added

Comment: Thanks for replay I tried getImagematrix and map points but it is not working...

Comment: Now I am keeping the scaletype same(default) still not working..

Comment: what have you tried? its just two lines of code to get the coordinates plus another 6-8 lines for. button placing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

final ImageView iv0 = new ImageView(this);
iv0.setImageResource(R.drawable.layer0);
ll.addView(iv0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

final FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
final ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(this);
iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.layer0);
fl.addView(iv1);
ll.addView(fl, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
setContentView(ll);
OnTouchListener l = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Matrix m = iv0.getImageMatrix();
        Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
        m.invert(inverse);
        float[] pts = { event.getX(), event.getY() };
        inverse.mapPoints(pts);

        // get the coordinates for other ImageView
        m = iv1.getImageMatrix();
        m.mapPoints(pts);

        // add the Button
        Button b = new Button(fl.getContext(), null, android.R.attr.buttonStyleSmall);
        int left = (int) pts[0];
        int top = (int) pts[1];
        b.setText("pos [" + left + "," + top + "]");
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
        p.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
        fl.addView(b, p);
        return false;
    }
};
iv0.setOnTouchListener(l);
```